# Triangle inequality square

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b \in [0,1], a+b=1$ and let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
How can we prove that $||ax+by||^2\leq (a||x||+b||y||)^2$?

What I've tried is to open the brackets but it's not very helpfull.

Thanks all.

Comment: Check your inequality please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite the left hand side as $\langle ax + by, ax + by \rangle$ and after some manipulation use the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that $$\varphi(x)=\|x\|^2$$ is a convex function and simply apply the inequality defining convexity. Observe that $a+b=1$, so, for instance, $b=1-a$.

This proof works for any normed space not only in the inner product space, as it is shown above.

It is easy to show that $\varphi$ is convex. Indeed, convexity of a norm follows by the properties of the norm: positive homogeneity and the triangle inequality. The composition of a convex function with the convex increasing function is also convex (trivial exercise).